# Application for posting activities on users wall

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, android-activity, facebook-c#-sdk

I wish to have an application that can post on facebook about all the activities of user on my website without asking for permission again and again.

I wish to do in the way [dailymotion](http://www.dailymotion.com) does everytime u watch a video there.

Can anyone guide me for the same. Just steps or some sample code will be suffice.

Thanks !

Comment: why -1  ? Does it violates any of the rules ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should learn about [open grpah](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/)

Here is the [tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/tutorial/)

Here are the [sample codes](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/samples/).

And also, there is an official php sdk and also JS sdk for facebook api, which makes life easier.